# How can I launch a function when I check a CheckBoxPreference with Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-preferences

The following code display a CheckBox control of `CheckBoxPreference` in a Preference UI using `androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat`.

I hope to a function named `myFunction()` can be launched when I check the  CheckBox control of
`CheckBoxPreference`, how can I do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 
    <CheckBoxPreference
        app:key="checkBoxDisplayPinPrompt"
        app:title="@string/preferencePromptPin"
        app:summary="@string/preferencePromptPinSummary"
        app:defaultValue="false"
    />

</PreferenceScreen>



import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
import info.dodata.voicerecorder.R


class FragmentPreference : PreferenceFragmentCompat(){

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.mypreference, rootKey)


    }

}
```

**Added Content**

To Shay Kin: Thanks!

Your code doesn't work, The Code A get the Error A, and the Code B get the Error B.

**Error  A**

*Type mismatch: inferred type is CheckBoxPreference? but CheckBoxPreference was expected*

**Code A**

```
val checkBox = findPreference("checkBoxDisplayPinPrompt") as CheckBoxPreference
checkBox.setOnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->
    if (newValue as Boolean) {
        //  function() your Fonction here
    }

    true
}
```

**Error B**

*Not enough information to infer type variable T*

**Code B**

```
 val checkBox = findPreference("checkBoxDisplayPinPrompt")!! as CheckBoxPreference
    checkBox.setOnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->
        if (newValue as Boolean) {
            //  function() your Fonction here
        }

        true
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your Preference by `findPreference("Pref_Name")` and you should use `setOnPreferenceChangeListener` to listen for changes :

I'm using  `androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'`

```
package com.fi.stackoverflow

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.preference.CheckBoxPreference
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat

class FragmentPreference : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_screen, rootKey)

        val checkBox = findPreference<CheckBoxPreference>("checkBoxDisplayPinPrompt")
        checkBox?.setOnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->
            //  function() your Fonction here
            if (newValue as Boolean) {
                Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "onPreferenceChange: $newValue")
            }
            true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question? Your code doesn't work.

Comment: Hi are you using CheckBoxPreference from androidx package ? if not please import a correct CheckBoxPreference and if also does not work please try without casting as CheckBoxPerefernce i updated by answer

Comment: I'm using CheckBoxPreference from androidx package

Comment: please try without casting as CheckBoxPreference !

Comment: I have import  a correct CheckBoxPreference

Comment: Maybe it should be `val checkBox = findPreference<CheckBoxPreference>("checkBoxDisplayPinPrompt")`

Comment: when i use this android Studio tel me `that No type arguments expected for fun findPreference(key: CharSequence!): Preference`

Comment: try only with this :`val checkBox = findPreference("checkBoxDisplayPinPrompt")`

Comment: Thanks! But only with this :val checkBox = findPreference("checkBoxDisplayPinPrompt") will not work

Comment: i found the probleme I'm using this in Gradel  `implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'`

Comment: the probleme is only with Version 1.1.1

Comment: My is `implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1"`

Comment: findPreference<CheckBoxPreference> it's work now with the Version 1.1.1

Comment: sorry we didn't use the same version of Gradel's Preference, i Updated my answer and I specify the version,please let me know if it's work